# React setState function from useState not updaing state value

Tags: reactjs, use-state

From the below code, while i do call the setSnake function with newer array , the snake variable ( state var ) does not update post the First key press...
on further key press, the value of snake is always {x:0, y:1 }( if you press the right key arrow

Any idea why?

```
const  SnakeBoard = () => {
    
    const width=10;
    const height=10;

    let initialRows = []
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
        initialRows.push([])
       for(let j=0;j<10;j++)
       {
        if( i==0 && j == 0)
             initialRows[i].push('snake')
        else
            initialRows[i].push('blank')
       }
    }

    const [rows,  setRows]  = useState(initialRows)
    const [snake, setSnake] = useState([{x:0,y:0}])
    
    const displaySnake = ()=>{
        
        const newRows = rows;
        snake.forEach(cell=>{
            newRows[cell.x][cell.y] = 'snake'
        })

        // console.log('newRows')  
        // console.log(newRows)  
        setRows(newRows);
    }

    const changeDirectionWithKeys = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const {key} = e  
        console.log(key)  
        moveSnake(key)
        
    }

    const moveSnake =(key) =>{
        const newSnake = []

        switch(key){

            case 'ArrowRight':
                newSnake.push({x: snake[0].x, y: snake[0].y + 1})
                break;

            case 'ArrowLeft':
                newSnake.push({x: snake[0].x, y:snake[0].y - 1})
                break;

            case 'ArrowUp':
                newSnake.push({x: snake[0].x - 1, y:snake[0].y})
                break;

            case 'ArrowDown':
                newSnake.push({x:snake[0].x + 1, y: snake[0].y})
                break;
        }


        if(snake.length !==1){
        snake.forEach(cell=> {
            newSnake.push(cell);
        })    
        }

        console.log(newSnake)
        console.log(snake)
        setSnake(...newSnake)
        displaySnake()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        
        window.addEventListener('keyup',changeDirectionWithKeys)

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keyup',changeDirectionWithKeys)
        }
    }, [])

    const diplayRows = rows.map( (row,index) =>       
        <li> 
            {row.map((e,ind)=>{
                switch(e){
                    case 'blank':                     
                    return <span>{index} - {ind} |</span> ;//<img src={Blank} alt="blank"></img>

                    case 'snake': 
                    return <span>{index} - {ind} |</span> ;//<img src={Snake} alt="snake"></img>
                }

            })}
        </li>       
            
    )

   

    return (
        <div>
            <UL>
                {diplayRows}
            </UL>           
        </div>
    )
}

export default SnakeBoard
```

Comment: You're using React, so why are you mutating the existing state? Never mutate state in React

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/snippet?

Comment: Try removing the spread operator (...) from setSnake(...newSnake). So change it to setSnake(newSnake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix your code (directions, updating), with some refactoring.
It's also not perfect but is easer.

```
const SnakeBoard = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [snake, setSnake] = useState([{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 0 }]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const width = 10;
    const height = 10;
    let initialRows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      initialRows.push("blank ".repeat(width).trim().split(' '));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { 
      initialRows[snake[i].y][snake[i].x] ="snake";
    }
    setRows(initialRows)
  }, [snake])

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeDirectionWithKeys = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { key } = e;
      // cut tail and push new head
      const [tail, ...newSnake] = snake.length > 1 ? snake : [null, ...snake]  ;
      const head = snake[snake.length-1]
        switch (key) {
        case "ArrowRight":
          newSnake.push({ x: head.x + 1 , y: head.y }); // fix
          break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
          newSnake.push({ x: head.x - 1 , y: head.y }); // fix
          break;
        case "ArrowUp":
          newSnake.push({ x: head.x, y: head.y - 1 }); // fix
          break;
        case "ArrowDown":
          newSnake.push({ x: head.x, y: head.y + 1  }); // fix
          break;
        default:
          break;  
      }
      setSnake(newSnake);
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", changeDirectionWithKeys);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", changeDirectionWithKeys);
    };
  }, [snake]);

  const diplayRows = rows.map((row, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      {row.map((e, ind) => {
        let cell = null
        switch (e) {
          case "blank":
            cell = <span key={ind}> .|</span>;
            break;
          case "snake":
            cell = <span key={ind}> s|</span>;
            break;
          default:
            break;  
        }
        return cell;
      })}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {diplayRows}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SnakeBoard;
```

Comment: @Daniel it works perfectly. Could you pls explain why putting the initiaRows and changeDirectionWithKeys in useEffect solves this?

Comment: and what is the error in my initial code ?

Comment: As wrote CertainPerformance and Jordan Maduro yesterday
1) mutating the existing state (it doesn't call render again!!)
2) setSnake(...newSnake); must be setSnake(newSnake);
3) moveSnake doesn't remove tail because displaySnake just add snake
4) clean code))

Comment: Thanks Danil... i learnt a new thing :-) ..  its actually this line which is mutating state 
 const newRows = rows;